# XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh doesn't work

Tags: xna

I have Windows 8 and installed VS2010 and VS2012. I've installed XNAGS 4 refresh. But when I open VS2010 there is still no templates for XNA. And in VS2012 there is only Pipeline Library and Content Project. I don't care about VS2012. How can I make it work in VS2010?

Comment: Are you sure XNA installed without errors?  It doesn't do so out of the box on Windows 8.  You need to install the Games for Windows Live client first.

Answer (score 2):

Try these visual studio XNA extensions, they work for VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013:

https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases

(Just download the latest release and follow the instructions that come with the package)

Comment: I installed the newest Game For Windows Live and it works. I'll try with this solution for VS2012 later

Comment: ah, so the install failed previously?